# Create array of NumericUpDowns and disable all of them?

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, numericupdown

I have several `NumericUpDowns` looking like this:

```
public void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged (object sender, EventArgs e){}
```

Now if one of them reaches a certain Value they all get disabled. I do this, with the following code as follows

```
if(Value == 0)
{
    numericUpDown1.Enabled = false;
    numericUpDown2.Enabled = false;
    numericUpDown3.Enabled = false;
    .....
}
```

And so on.

My Question is: can I declare an array in my public form or something that includes all the `NumericUpDowns` I want disabled and then disable them calling the array?

Comment: Put them in a Panel, disable the panel.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using .NET 3.5 or newer one you can access all controls of type by:

```
var my controls = Controls.OfType<NumericUpDown>();
```

And the iterate through:

```
foreach(var control in controls)
{
    if(controls.Where(control => control.Value == 0).Any()) 
    {
        control.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Bartosz...it will disable forever...you missed value condition...value should be zero

Comment: That's true. Inside foreach loop add if statement, look at my answer. It's already edited.

Comment: How is this possible to use `Where` after `foreach`? Also `if(control.value == 0) 
    {
        control.Enabled = false;` is incorrect because OP said *if one of them reaches a certain Value **they all get disabled**.*

Comment: You're right. That happens when you write code in browser without checking it. I edited my answer.

Comment: This is still incorrect because this will disable just a control which it's value is zero but OP wants ***they all get disabled***.

Comment: `ForEach` after a Boolean result?

Comment: You're right, that's won't work. I deleted that option.

Comment: I haven't got your codes to work, i solved it with a void in which i disable them all.